# How to highlight items in a ListView

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I am using the code below, but it doesn't work. Why ?

MainActivity:

```
final SongAdapter songAdt = new SongAdapter(getApplicationContext(), songList);
lv.setAdapter(songAdt);

lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

           view.setSelected(true);
           ...
```

ListView:

```
<ListView android:id="@+id/lvP" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:fadeScrollbars="false"
    android:layout_height="0dp" android:layout_weight="0.57"android:divider="#555555"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_key" />
```

bg_key.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector
    android:id="@+id/myselector"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- Non focused states -->
    <item
        android:state_focused="false"
        android:drawable="@color/activated_color" />
    <item
        android:state_activated="false"
        android:drawable="@color/activated_color" />
    <item
        android:state_selected="true"
        android:drawable="@color/activated_color" />
    <item
        android:drawable="@color/default_color" />
</selector>
```

color.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="pressed_color">#222222</color>
    <color name="activated_color">#1d1d1d</color>
    <color name="checked_color">#ff0000</color>
    <color name="default_color">#111111</color>
</resources>
```

EDIT:

As suggested, I have removed android:background="@drawable/bg_key" from the ListView and then I added it to the

song_layout.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="0dp"
    android:paddingRight="0dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_key">


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/song_cover"
        android:scaleType = "fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/note"
        android:background="#171717"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="1dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/song_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Title"
        android:textColor="#fcdb8c"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:textStyle="normal"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/song_cover"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/song_cover"
        android:lines="1"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:paddingRight="40dp"
        android:paddingLeft="3dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/song_duration"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:text="0:00"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:textSize="11sp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|top" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/song_artist"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Artist"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:layout_weight="0.67"
        android:layout_below="@+id/song_title"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/song_cover"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/song_cover"
        android:lines="1"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:paddingRight="40dp"
        android:paddingLeft="3dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You must use selector on each item not on listview

Comment: try removing android:background="@drawable/bg_key

Comment: @M.Wiśnicki I have just tryed: I have removed android:background="@drawable/bg_key" from the ListView and then I added it to the <RelativeLayout in the song_layout.xml file. But it doesn't work :(

Comment: @CoDfather Removed and it doesn't work.

Comment: @M.Wiśnicki I have edited the code above as you suggested.

Comment: plaese change your song_layout.xml  according this code..
android:padding="5dp"  Main layout and remove background and
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_key"
        android:padding="5dp">
add new layout item root

Answer (score 0):

change your selector property to this and use background as it is in your edited Que`android:state_focused="true" 
android:state_activated="true"
android:state_selected="true"`.

Answer (score 0):

Use this on List Item Click :

```
    View rowView = view;
setItemSelected(rowView); //use this inside on item click

 public void setItemSelected(View view){
    View rowView = view;
    TextView tv = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView_two); // try your text view here
    tv.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
}
```